# Alternatives to XMLHttpRequest when fetching upload progress

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've been noodling with an XMLHttpRequest to update users on upload progress for large files in a web form:

```
function progressHandler(event) {
    var percent = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
    $('#loader').text( percent + '%' );
}

$("#Submit").click(function () {
    var file = document.getElementById('fileupload').files[0];
    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("new-job-form"));

    ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            // we'll come back to this
        }
    }

    ajax.open("POST", "@Url.Action("NewJob", "Home")");
    ajax.send(formData);
});
```

And this works fine, up until the point the load completes.

My web application backend is written in .Net MVC and originally used this after the file upload was complete:

```
return RedirectToAction("FieldMapping", new { jobId = job.JobId });
```

This no longer works, because I've made the call asynchronous by invoking `XMLHttpRequest`.

The alternative is to return Json containing the target Url and redirect to that. This is a pain, and I'm having trouble getting it work properly. There are a few questions about this already on SO and the consensus is: don't do this. The whole point of Ajax is deal with partial responses, not whole-page redirects.

Which I understand, but I don't know of another way I can monitor the progress of a file upload and send it back to the user without using `XMLHttpRequest`. Is there another way to approach this, so I can just `RedirectToAction` after the request is complete?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. In a web browser, you have normal request, which will change the entire view in the browser to a different page or AJAX requests, which allow you to maintain the current view, while still contacting a server. For the latter, `XMLHttpRequest` is the JavaScript object that makes that possible. There is no alternative.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Apologies if I have not expressed this properly. I understand the difference and I did not originally need or want to make partial calls with ajax. But I do need to monitor the progress of uploaded files: is there an alternative way of doing *that* without using ajax?

Comment: That was my point. How do you imagine you'd do that without AJAX? Monitoring anything means requesting the status from a remote server. Client-side, AJAX is your only method to do that, without literally requesting the whole page again from the server.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Yeah, while I was testing error handling in the process, this suddenly occurred to me. Can't update a user on progress without making a partial call to check progress! Apologies for wasting your time with a such a poor, ill considered question. Will delete shortly.

Comment: I suppose you could technically use WebSockets, which is *technically* not AJAX, although the principles at play are very much the same. The only real difference is that WebSockets create a two-way connection between the client and server, rather than the traditional request-response connection. You'll need a server-side package that can handle this communication (SignalR) and a capable web server (IIS 8+), though.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thanks. Can't delete as it has an answer - I've added my close vote instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this: [Using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

> Progress events exist for both download and upload transfers. The download events are fired on the XMLHttpRequest object itself, as shown in the above sample. The upload events are fired on the XMLHttpRequest.upload object, as shown below:
>
> ```
> var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
>
> oReq.upload.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress);
>
> oReq.upload.addEventListener("load", transferComplete);
> oReq.upload.addEventListener("error", transferFailed);
> oReq.upload.addEventListener("abort", transferCanceled);
>
> oReq.open();
> ```

Why not do your "redirect" in the "load" event handler, which lets you know that the upload is finished? You could also use this:

> One can also detect all three load-ending conditions (abort, load, or error) using the loadend event:
>
> ```
> req.addEventListener("loadend", loadEnd);
>
> function loadEnd(e) {
>   console.log("The transfer finished (although we don't know if it succeeded or not).");
> }
> ```